# Difference between poweroff and reboot

Tags: debian, shutdown, reboot

I have an embedded device that is built on a Raspberry Pi. I am not the designer of the device, but support from the manufacturer is non-existent so I am on my own to debug.  Some of the services that are running mysteriously stall after an indeterminant amount of time.  It's been very hard to debug, but a general trend I  have found is that a `sudo reboot` will not repair the stalled process, but for some reason a `sudo poweroff` does solve the problem. (It might be useful to note that forcefully pulling the power also does not solve the issue, so I have concluded that some part of the `poweroff` procedure is fixing it). I am trying to debug this so I can reset the device in the future without having to cycle the power (as a poweroff requires a physical power interrupt to start again). Ideally, I will also uncover the source of the problem, but at this point treating the symptoms instead of the cause is a satisfactory course of action.

So, my question is: what does `sudo poweroff` do, exactly, that `sudo reboot` does not, so I can begin my search?

Comment: A reboot will not interrupt power, but just cause the cpu and its local peripherals to reset. Any hats attached will not see that and carry on as if nothing happened. Power off is a misnomer. It does not actually power off as voltage is still being supplied. Therefore, you will probably be yanking the power. And when that happens, the attached hats will reset.

Comment: This is what I thought, but if I merely yank power (without first doing `sudo poweroff`), that also does not reset correctly.

Comment: Really not enough info. All we know is that you have a RPi.

Comment: `reboot` and `poweroff` are run via systemd. Maybe there is a service that is `[Install]`ed with `WantedBy=poweroff.target` but not `reboot.target` - try checking for `poweroff.target.wants` directories in `/etc/systemd/system`, `/usr/lib/systemd/system` or `/usr/share/systemd/system` - alternatively via `systemctl list-depenencies poweroff.target`.